# How do I select * AS

Tags: postgresql

I have 8 tables with duplicate column names. This is not allowing me to create a view.
Is there a way append prefix to column?

For ex:-

```sql
select table1.* as prefix1.table1.*
       table2.* as prefix2.table2.*
       table3.* as prefix3.table3.*
FROM table 1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
inner join table3 on table2.id = table3.id
```

I know it is not natively supported but looking for creative ideas. TIA

Comment: Question: Why do you have eight tables all with the same Primary Key in the first place?

Comment: `*` means *all columns*. But `AS` only provides a *single column* alias per instance of it. So syntactically what you're asking doesn't really make sense. But I understand that your underlying goal is just to look for a shorthand to alias a bunch of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Select * AS`.
You have to select every column name explicit by name, like:

```
CRETE OR REPLACE VIEW YourViewName
AS 
SELECT Table1.Column1 AS TBL1_COL1, 
       Table1.Column2 AS TBL1_COL2, 
       Table1.Column3 AS TBL1_COL3, 
       ....
       Table2.Column1 AS TBL2_COL1,
       Table2.Column2 AS TBL2_COL2,
       Table2.Column3 AS TBL2_COL3,
       ...
       Table3.Column1 AS TBL3_COL1,
       Table3.Column2 AS TBL3_COL2,
       ...
FROM   Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
       ON Table1.id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
       ON Table2.id = Table3.id
```

This gives you more control over the view you are getting, and (I believe) if you use column names in the query instead of just `*`, the query might even run faster as the database server does not have to figure out all the column names as you already have given it in the query.